# SATA Port vs Using a USB hub in a SATA Port

Tags: usb, sata, nas

I was wondering if there is any downside to using a USB hub on a single SATA port to add 2-3 more HDD's as opposed to adding more SATA Hubs via the PCI card?

Background content:
I'm currently pulling out a motherboard from an old laptop to setup a simple NAS that can store some files, stream a few movies here and there, nothing too serious nor heavy duty.

I came across this Simple DIY Nas on instructables (google for it as i can't post links) and saw that he used a USB hub on a single SATA Port, which ideally would be cost saving for me as I don't have to get a PCI card, however I'd like to know if there is any drawbacks to doing so!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're talking about [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cheap-Quite-DIY-NAS/).

USB hub is a device that lets you connect multiple USB devices to one USB port. You can't connect USB to SATA or SATA to USB, they are completely different and incompatible.

Author of this tutorial bought 4 portable hard disk enclosures that act as SATA-to-USB converters. Drives have SATA interfaces, but enclosures convert them to USB. Then these USB ports are connected to a regular USB hub which is connected to one USB port.

Unless your laptop motherboard and enclosures support USB 3.0, this setup will be rather slow. USB 2.0 maxes out on about 30 MB/s. RAID0-ing drives won't help because the hub will be a bottleneck (and reliability would be 4 times lower).

On the other hand, if MoBo doesn't support gigabit LAN, this speed would be sufficient. 100 Mbps LAN has 12.5 MB/s bandwidth, real throughput would be even lower. Wi-Fi 802.11n has [about 50-80 Mbps throughput](http://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-the-actual-real-life-speed-of-wireless-374), so it's even worse.

I don't think you'll be able to connect a PCI SATA controller to a laptop motherboard, they just don't have any PCI slots.

Comment: The speed limitations of USB2 are roughly in the right ballpark but the reasoning given in the linked answer is completely wrong - it was wrong 4 years ago and is even more wrong today. "Wi-Fi 802.11n has about 50 Mbps bandwidth" is also extremely misleading.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq You're right, I meant throughput, not bandwidth. I have also removed the answer link and just tested my drive in a USB 2.0 enclosure, Windows reported ~27 MB/s (copying a huge file through USB 2.0 port to a SSD).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect an USB hub to a SATA port. Those are not compatible.

What you can do is:

- Multiple harddisks, each on a SATA to USB adaptor,
  And then connect each USB port from that via a [powered] USB hub,
  and connect the hub to an USB port (not a SATA port!) on the laptop.
  Combined speed for USB2 would be about 30MB/sec. USB3 speeds would be higher, but require more modern equipment.
- Use a SATA [port multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier). This does not involve USB at all, though it can involve some sort of hub (for command-based switching).